# odd issue with funny characters in Joomla/ Jomsocial

Tags: joomla, character, jomsocial

I hope someone can help me with this issue. 
For a few months (since last August) there has been an ongoing issue on my site with strange characters appearing all over the place - especially in user generated content.

I have searched and searched for answers but nothing ever seems to work, although the most pressing (in the blog component) has been resolved by setting JCE to validate HTML - which is does fine in the Blogging component ([EasyBlog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/12630)) but doesn't anywhere else (where it is less critical but still an issue).

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Checked the site from multiple machines, multiple browsers - no difference.
2. Checked the MySQL database and table collation - which are `utf8_general_ci`
3. Added `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` and `AddCharset UTF-8` .php to the .htaccess files. I played about with these for ages and these two seemed to be the only combination which didn't crash the site.
4. Have checked the HTML headers and they definitely have the correct content encoding types (set to `UTF-8`)
5. I have tried different WSIWIG editors to no avail. Besides it is often in the code output where the characters appear - typically a A next to a »

I have tried a hack to force the connection script to `UTF-8` but this causes the site to crash.

If anyone has any ideas at all as to what I can do still ... I'm all ears (please)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Paullette, this would be much easier if you could provide a link to a page that exhibits the problem and details of where the content is coming from that includes the spurious characters.

Comment: agree with @cppl; if you move to a clean development machine with no .htaccess do you still get the issue?

Comment: hi - @cppl - you can see the issue on http://www.fabulous-women.co.uk/index.php/meetings-events/viewevent/333-wokingham?groupid=31

Comment: Riccardo - unfortunately I don't have access to a clean dev machine. However I have installed the site in a new clean environment recently and the problem just got worse :(

Comment: @cppl - the content is captured using JCE on the front end of the site by the user community. It is then stored in a mySQL database where very often the characters don't appear so I know it is going in ok ... it's displaying which seems to be the issue. Having said that a funny chacter does appear at random from the scripts themselves. Some of them I have managed to remove by replacing with the html friendly representation for the character. But this is not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is running PHP 5.4+ I would suggest that you try [the following solution described in the JCE forums](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/forum/jce-editor/haunted-by-a-weird-character-a/layout/default):

> In the Editor Global Configuration, set "`Entity Encoding`" to "`UTF-8`"
>
> In the "Custom Configuration Variables" field, add:
>
> `keep_nbsp:0`

The keep an eye out for the JCE 2.3.2 release which will address this issue.

Things to note:

1. anywhere the spurious â or Â is occurring will have to be edited to remove the characters (once the changes above have been applied to JCE).
2. the problem is Joomla! 2.5.x's use of [`get_html_translation_table()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php) which relies on default values and PHP 5.4 changed the default `encoding` parameter to `UTF-8`. Previously it defaulted to `ISO-8859-1`
3. For the core you could try and modify `_decode()` in `/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php`, look for the line (*around 644*):

   `$trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);`

and change it to:

```
$trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Comment: Many thanks. I've tried this but the problem persists :(. I will give it a proper test later - however it doesn't solve the issue across the site generally. For example - if you look at the home page at http://www.fabulous-women.co.uk you'll see the odd  â appearing, also the odd Â even though these elements are not generated via the JCE editor. The other issue is, in looking at the text via PHPmyAdmin or coping into Notepad++ these characters don't appear so removing them is proving somewhat problematic.

Comment: Further update .. thanks v.much this does seem to have helped in that the A characters are not appearing all over. Now they only appear whenever there is a £ sign. The issue with the â and Â generated via the site core scripts remains.

Comment: Hi Paullette — see updated answer point #3. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi there ... thanks v. much. Changed the line of code .. and got this error on all pages:This web page is not available
The web page at http://www.fabulous-women.co.uk/index.php/meetings-events/viewevent/333-wokingham?groupid=31 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error. I did try the full hack as on the Joomla site but the same thing happened and I had to revert to the old code.

Comment: Sort of solved this. Just as a FYI for anyone else struggling with the same issue: 
1. Change your Database type to MySql (mine was set to MySQLi and that is what was causing most of the problems). 

There were still odd characters creeping in, this is what I did in the JCE configuration panel: 
1. Set validate HTML to Yes
2. Set Doctype to HTML4
3. Set Entity encoding to named
4. Set Plug iin mode to No 
5. Added keep_nbsp:0 to the custom configuration variable. 

Seems to have solved it. Or least, lets see.